# Convert a vertical data in a excel sheet with one header

Tags: excel, database, vba, text-parsing

I have a problem converting a long list of vertical address data into a a standard horizontal excel sheet with a header file.

What I have is this:

```
Name     Text Doe
Email    me@you.com
Operator     Someone
Product/Service  name of product
Phone   123 1234567
Company  ABC Company
Referrer URL     https://www.google.com.my/
Search Engine    Google
IP   210.186.133.177
Country/Region   Malaysia
State    Kuala Lumpur
City     Kuala Lumpur[Client Info]
Language     en-GB
Time Zone    GMT +08
Name     Text Doe
Email    me@you.com
Operator     Someone
Product/Service  name of product
Phone   123 1234567
Company  ABC Company
Referrer URL     https://www.google.com.my/
Search Engine    Google
IP   210.186.133.177
Country/Region   Malaysia
State    Kuala Lumpur
City     Kuala Lumpur[Client Info]
Language     en-GB
Time Zone    GMT +08
Name     Text Doe
Email    me@you.com
Operator     Someone
Product/Service  name of product
Phone   123 1234567
Company  ABC Company
Referrer URL     https://www.google.com.my/
Search Engine    Google
IP   210.186.133.177
Country/Region   Malaysia
State    Kuala Lumpur
City     Kuala Lumpur[Client Info]
Language     en-GB
Time Zone    GMT +08
```

I try to find some automated way to parse this into a standard excel sheet where the labels on the side are horizontal on the top with the info below so that I can import it to a crm.

```
Name     Email   Operator    Product/Service     Phone  Company  Referrer URL    Search Engine   Google    IP    Country/Region  State   City    Language    Time Zone
```

with the info on the cells below. Is there a easy way to do this in a VB script or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

1. First **Past** all the data to the excel file.
2. Then **replace** the string '     ' with ',' (using <kbd>Ctrl + h</kbd>).
3. Use the **Text to Columns** (in Data) function to make it into columns.

[image]

4. **Copy** everything.
5. Past it using the **Past Special** <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + V</kbd>

[image]

6. Mark **Transpose** and click OK.

[image]

Comment: that is nice to know and useful. However, it does not completely what I need. It does convert it into a very long horizontal line. But I have 6000 entries and need one header with the labels

Name     Email   Operator    Product/Service     Phone  Company  Referrer URL    Search Engine   Google    IP    Country/Region  State   City    Language    Time Zone

Than with the 6000 records underneath one per line. So that I can import it as a CSV file into the CRM.

Comment: Let me explain where I tried to go with this. But my Excel formula skills are a bit limited.
So I thought it might be possible to mace a sheet with the headlines. Than parse the sheet with my list to say (If cell A contains the word "Name" than take the content of cell B and copy it into my new sheet under name) to say it in plain English.
I found something similar but I was not completely able to do it.
My base was this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXrViFkPROM
Theoretically this should be similarly possible for my case?

Comment: I tried to Have my List in A1 for the labels and B2 for the value

Then I used: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Name",A1)),B1,"")
This does work as long I replace the search value with the same label word. But it it will have 11 empty cells because each word only repeats every 11 cells.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished my task.
I made a simple formula to parse the cells and repeat it every 14 rows since there is 14 labels that repeat over and over.

The formula I used is:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,ROW(B2)*14+COLUMN(B2))
```

Because Column A are the labels and Column B is the data. 
So this simply parses every 14th row to the list.